# Docker: Not able to create postgresql role when container is starting

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am learning docker. i have created postgresql image and when container is starting i am trying to create role "root" but "root" role is not getting created..

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby
MAINTAINER Eric Mill "eric@konklone.com"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential
RUN gem install rails
RUN mkdir /home/project
RUN apt install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib
#RUN rm -rf /etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf
#RUN rm -rf /etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf
#COPY ./demo/postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/13/main
#COPY ./demo/pg_hba.conf /etc/postgresql/13/main
RUN apt install -y vim
```

docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.9'
services:
 application:
  build: .
  image: 'xyza'
  working_dir: '/home/project/demo'
  volumes:
   - type: bind
     source: .
     target: /home/project
  command: bash -c "cd /home/project/demo && rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle install &&  rails s"
 db:
  build: .
  image: 'xyz'
  ports: 
   - "5432:5432"
  working_dir: '/home/project'
  volumes:
   - type: bind
     source: .
     target: /home/project
  command: bash -c "cd /home/project && ./pgsql.sh"
```

pgsql.sh file

```
#! /bin/bash
service postgresql start
su postgres
createuser root
psql
ALTER USER root WITH PASSWORD 'root';
exit;
exit;
echo 'hello world6'
service postgresql restart
sleep 3600
```

i was expecting pgsql.sh file will create role 'root' but this is not happening instead i am getting below error when i am running docker-compose up db

```
db_1           | Starting PostgreSQL 13 database server: main.
db_1           | createuser: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
db_1           | psql: error: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
db_1           | ./pgsql.sh: line 8: ALTER: command not found
```

Why i am not able to create role "root"? if i am executing commands from pgsql.sh file by going into container using command `docker exec -it sanjay_db_1 bash` then i am able to create "root" role. why i am not able to create role when container is starting during docker-compose up db?

Comment: According to the error message, you are trying to connect as 'root' in order to create root, which of course can't work.

Comment: @jjanes where in my code i am trying to connect as 'root' ? 

 The problem is with 'su postgres' statement.. it looks like it has no impact inside docker-container.. if i run docker container in bash mode and execute pgsql.sh  script by skipping 'su postgres'  then i am able to repdouce the same error.. need to check why su postgres has no impact if executing during docker-compose up

Comment: You didn't say you were, your error message said you were.  I just interpreted  your error message back to you.  But in a script, `su postgres` just opens a new shell as postgres, which does not read the rest of the script. Since the new shell doesn't have any input, it just exits, and the original shell (still being root, I guess) resumes running the rest of the script.  In bash, you could use the "heredoc" construct `<<<` to feed lines of the script-file into the input of the new shell.

Answer (score -1):

As per @jjanes comment i used heredoc in my shell script and it worked for me.

```
#! /bin/bash
    
service postgresql start
su postgres << BLOCK
createuser root
psql
ALTER USER root WITH PASSWORD 'root';
BLOCK
service postgresql restart
sleep 3600
```